# PostgreSQL/PostGIS: shp2pgsql INSERT instead of Creating a new table

Tags: postgresql, postgis, shapefile, pgadmin

Hi I am very new to PostgreSQL/PostGIS and just learned how to convert Shapefiles into SQL file and import it to PostGIS using the shp2pgsql by following [this](http://www.gistutor.com/postgresqlpostgis/4-beginner-postgresqlpostgis-tutorials/18-importing-shapefile-gis-data-into-postgresql.html) tutorial. What I noticed is that whenever I convert a Shapefile, it generates an SQL file that has a CREATE TABLE statement. Now my question is, is there a way or is it even possible to INSERT a new Shapefile(with new set of layers) into an existing table rather than creating a new one?

I hope I explained it well. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use append option in your command line.
Like this:

```
.\shp2pgsql.exe -c -I -g "geom" fistShpFile.shp
.\shp2pgsql.exe -a  -g "geom"   nextShpFile.shp
.\shp2pgsql.exe -a  -g "geom"   nextShpFile.shp
...
```

> ```
> (-d|a|c|p) These are mutually exclusive options:
>
> -d Drops the table, then recreates it and populates it with current shape file data.
> -a Appends shape file into current table, must be exactly the same table schema.
> -c Creates a new table and populates it, default if you do not specify any options. 
> -p Prepare mode, only creates the table.
> ```

http://www.bostongis.com/pgsql2shp_shp2pgsql_quickguide.bqg

Or use `shp2pgsql -?` for other options.